# CAML Query Where (x AND y) OR Z

Tags: caml-query, caml

I've been struggling with this all day. I've referenced several SO questions/answers but to no avail. Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I also cannot use a CAML Builder, unfortunately, due to some security restrictions.

Here is my custom list, users:

```
LastName | FirstName | NameID
```

I'm trying to write my CAML query to say, WHERE (LastName = X AND FirstName = Y) OR NameID = Z

I can do the first part just fine, grabbing where LastName = X and FirstName = Y.

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='LastName' />
            <Value Type='Text'>Doe</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='FirstName' />
            <Value Type='Text'>John</Value>
        </Eq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

But as soon as I try to say that statement OR where NameID = Z, I run into issues. I've tried several queries, my latest being:

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='LastName' />
            <Value Type='Text'>Doe</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='FirstName' />
            <Value Type='Text'>John</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Or>
            <Eq><FieldRef Name='Name' /><Value Type='Text'>JDoe123</Value></Eq>
        </Or>
    </And>
</Where>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

`<Or>` should be the outer one and `<And>` should be inside.

Try below:

```
    <Where>
      <Or>
                <Eq><FieldRef Name='Name' /><Value Type='Text'>JDoe123</Value></Eq>

        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='LastName' />
                <Value Type='Text'>Doe</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='FirstName' />
                <Value Type='Text'>John</Value>
            </Eq>

        </And>
</Or>
    </Where>
```

Comment: This is the general approach: A useful way to think about CAML logic statements is to treat them like functions: `AND(thing1, thing2)`, `OR(thing1, thing2)`, `OR(AND(thing1, thing2), thing3)` etc.

Comment: @John-M Perfect explanation

Comment: You need to squint and turn your head sideways to get CAML right. It actually makes a lot of sense once you get it, and its odd structure makes it easier to build up programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

While writing CAML Query you should keep few points in mind.

- Every `<Or>` / `<And>` can consist of only 2 conditions

> ```
>     <And>
>           <Eq>
>               <FieldRef Name='LastName' />
>               <Value Type='Text'>Doe</Value>
>           </Eq>
>           <Eq>
>               <FieldRef Name='FirstName' />
>               <Value Type='Text'>John</Value>
>          </Eq>
>     </And>
> ```

- If so try formatting it so that above `<And>` becomes 1 conditional block.

Now you can pair it with another condition

```
 <Or>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='Name' /><Value Type='Text'>JDoe123</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Another conditional block here>
 </Or>
```

Here you can replace `<Another conditional block here>` with your previously created conditional block of `<and>` so it will again be treated as a single condition

So In all your query will look like :

```
<Where>
      <Or>
           <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name='Name' /><Value Type='Text'>JDoe123</Value>
           </Eq>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='LastName' />
                <Value Type='Text'>Doe</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='FirstName' />
                <Value Type='Text'>John</Value>
            </Eq>
        </And>
     </Or>
</Where>
```